# Add transparent layer to image

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Im trying to implement a crop feature for my app like the one Instagram has.

Example: http://i.imgur.com/Dq12OAx.png

I need to create an UIView in the form of a rectangle with a square "hole" in the middle.
I have no idea where to start so all help is appreciated.

Comment: @Shog9: I hope the new question follows the site recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty easy.  Just subclass UIView, and override drawrect.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    //draw the non-transparent view here, or fill the whole view like
    [[UIColor blackColor] setFill];
    UIRectFill( rect);

    //define the position and size of the "hole"
    CGRect yourHole = CGRectMake(left, top, width, height);

    //fill that section with clear color
    [[UIColor clearColor] setFill];
    UIRectFill( yourHole );
}
```

Comment: @HaIR, thanks for the example. But although the smaller rectangle is clearColor, i am not able to do user interaction with the layer below.
I have a scrollrect which have a imgview. On top of this I have the UIView with the hole. What I want to achieve is to be able to pan the image in the scrollView through the transparented hole. Is this possible?